# ajaxfileupload.js how to rename uploaded file and set destination folder (to save to)?

Tags: jquery

I am planning to use ajaxfileupload.js for uploading file via ajax call. Using it with, jeditable

I am not able to figure how to give destination folder to save the uploaded file? Also if possible, can I change the name of the file before I save it on server?

Answer (score 0):

you have to do this server-side with the language of your choice. the ajaxfileupload-"destination" is a script that processes your file(s).

Comment: tx I am using perl CGI on the server end. where is the script you are referring to, located?

Comment: you have to specify the location of your perl-script that handles your uploads in your ajaxfileupload-script. but for the perlupload-handling itself, i just can tell you: search for "perl handle http uploads", because i have no idea of perl ;-)